# Ensuring component re-initialization when route params change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes defined:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/project/:id/search" component={SearchPage} />
    <Route path="/project/:id/upload" component={UploadPage} />
</Switch>
```

The issue is that search results (local state of the `SearchPage` component) remain when you navigate to another project's search page. I could solve it by manually clearing state in `willReceiveProps` when the ID changes but I want to avoid that as there are several sub-pages of `/project` that would need the logic.

Using `render={()=> <SearchPage />}` made no difference.

What's a clean way of ensuring that my components get re-initialized when the parameter in the URL changes?

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'key reset state' technique: if special prop `key` is different React will for sure recreate element instead of updating.

So it may be

```
<Route 
  path="/project/:id/search" 
  render={({ match: {params: {id} } })=> <SearchPage key={id} />} 
/>
```

To me this affects readability in bad way. So using `componentDidUpdate`(`willReceiveProps` [is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)) seems to be better maintainable.

Comment: Does it even need a key, if he passes id as props and link the state of the component to the props, there should be no need for a complete re-creation.

Comment: if change for `match.params.id` is not handled in `componentDidUpdate` and result are loaded in `componentDidMount` you either need to use `key` or implement `cDU`. there are no other ways.

Comment: Hooks will do it

Comment: what hooks? what do you mean?